# How to include a text file in HTML such that all content shows without specifying width and height

Tags: html, text-files

A basic HTML web page must insert raw-text from a text file. This can be done by means of an `object`, like this:

```
<p><div><object width="720" height="1200" data="ranking.txt"></object></div></p>
```

Now, `width` and `height` must be specified in order to show all the content and avoid the scroll bars.

Is there any HTML5-compliant way to self-adjust size to the file's content (both in number of lines, and lines length?

Comment: Maybe you can do it using CSS. Inline it would look like `style="width:auto; height:auto"`

Comment: @xanoetux tested, but no, it doesn't work. Actually the text does not get the color or font-size specifications, either.

Comment: <object> tag seems to be rather unflexible according to style. So either include the text server-side or using JS to make things work. Without, there is probably no way to get it.